# lowest and biggest values problems with conditions in C

Tags: c

trying to find the smallest and largest value in the array, I'm getting the wrong small value. Why ?

```
biggerY=lowerY=arrY[0];
for(int loop2 = 1; loop2<10; loop2++)
{
    if(arrY[loop2]>biggerY && arrY[loop2] != 0)
        biggerY=arrY[loop2];
    if(arrY[loop2]<lowerY && arrY[loop2] != 0)
        lowerY=arrY[loop2];
}
```

my input :

```
1 2 
2 1
```

The values ​​on the right are saved in my array(arrY[10]).
expected biggerY: 2
expected lowerY : 1

my output for biggerY : 2
my output for lowery : 0 (but it should be 1)

thanks.

Comment: You do not check condition `arrY[0] != 0`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that irrespective of the size of the `arrY` array, you run the loop till 10. You should run the loop till its size.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: uninitialized variables are not 0.  Testing for 0 does not tell you whether you are within bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that irrespective of the size of the arrY array, you run the loop till 10. You should run the loop till its size.
Assuming the size of arrY is in the variable `n`

```
biggerY=lowerY=arrY[0];
for(int loop2 = 1; loop2<n; loop2++)
{
    if(arrY[loop2]>biggerY && arrY[loop2] != 0)
        biggerY=arrY[loop2];
    if(arrY[loop2]<lowerY && arrY[loop2] != 0)
        lowerY=arrY[loop2];
}
```

Comment: How does this explain the reported behavior? If `arrY[loop2]` is zero, the test fails, and `lowerY` is not updated. If it is not zero, `lowerY` might be updated, but not to zero. The C standard does allow an uninitialized object to act as if it has different values at different times, so it could pass the test (by appearing to be non-zero when used for the test) and update `lowerY` with zero (by appearing to be zero when used for the assignment), but that is not likely. Most likely, there is something else wrong.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The input case that the author gave was 2 numbers but he was running the loop till 10. So, there were garbage values in the array which were creating problems

Comment: Again, how does this explain the reported behavior? If the “garbage value” in `arrY[loop2]` is zero, it does not update `lowerY`. If it is non-zero, it does not udpate `lowerY` to be zero. So how can the OP get an incorrect value of zero in `lowerY`?

Comment: I understand you now. But running the loop till arbitrary size is a serious problem too in my opinion.